# SVN server not showing repository files

Tags: svn

i have set  a svn server on linux. I have created a repository, projects inside it with folder structure branches,tags,trunk with command svn import . I have a problem that i can see a complete directory structure and files in folder from client side (using eclipse + subclips)  but i am not getting the where will server stores files ?

Please if any one has solution reply me.

in short i can't get the location of project files on server (repository)

when i run command svn ls --- it will show all project list

Answer (score 2):

SVN stores the files in a database.  The version controlled files are not stored directly on the file system.  You will not be able to access the version controlled files without some form of an SVN client.